# Prove using a proof sequence and justify each step

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Prove using a proof sequence that the argument is valid [ A --> (B ∨ C) ] ∧ B' ∧ C' --> A'

I'm having some trouble figuring the proof out here.  Here is what I have so far.  Is this on the right track?

1. A-->(B ∨ C)     (Given)
2. B’               (Given)
3. C’               (Given) ?
4. B’ ∧ C’          unsure here
5. (B∨C)’           DeMorgan's Law? using 2 and 3.
6. A’               Contradiction using 1 and 5

Prove using a proof sequence that the argument is valid (hint: the last A’ has to be
inferred). Justify each step. 
(A-->C) ∧ (C-->B’) ∧ B-->A’

This one I'm not really sure where to go with it, any help would be appreciated.

1. (A-->C)
2. (C-->B’)
3. B
4. A’

Edit: Apologies there were some typos in the original question, ' is used for negation in this case.

Comment: What does the prime denote? I'd assume it is the complement, i.e., the negation, but I see you're using $\sim$ for the negation. The first one seems to have a few mistakes which I can't explain in a comment. But how is, for instance, $B'$ a given?

Comment: In your initial line, you type "C;". I think you mean C'

Comment: In both proof you have to *assume* $A$ and then derive a contradiction; with it, by $\lnot$-introduction, conclude with $\lnot A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\color{gray}{\boxed{\color{black}{
\because\quad \text{Assuming } A 
\\[2ex]
\qquad A ,\; [ (A\to B\vee C)\wedge B' \wedge C' ]
\\ \quad \vdash (\text{ conjunction elimination: } S\wedge T \vdash S, \text{ and } S\wedge T\vdash T)
\\ \qquad A ,\; (A\to B\vee C) ,\; B' ,\; C'
\\ \quad \vdash (\text{ implication elimination: } S\to T, S \vdash T)
\\ \qquad (B\vee C),\; B',\; C'
\\ \quad \vdash (\text{ disjunctive syllogism: } S', S\vee T \vdash T)
\\ \qquad C,\; C'
\\ \quad \vdash (\text{ contradiction: } S', S\vee S' \vdash \bot)
\\ \qquad \bot
\\[2ex]
\therefore \quad (A\to B\vee C)\wedge B' \wedge C' \;\vdash\; A'
}}}$

Comment: What does the upside down "therefore" symbol mean?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD "$~\because~$" (mathjax: `\because`) means "because".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using prime to denote the negation, and that you meant C' instead of C; in the first line of your post, then your first proof is correct.

[EDIT] As pointed out in the comments below, you only really have one given. That is the left side of the initial logic statement: $[A \rightarrow (B\vee C)] \wedge B' \wedge C'$.

Your initial first three statements (now statements 2 through 4) all derive from this given. By specialization, if $A\wedge B$ is true then $A$ is true (as is $B$).

Working from that, your fourth statement does come from the previous 2 - it's called Conjunction. If B' is true and C' is true, then $B'\wedge C'$ is also true. Your statement 5 is an application of DeMorgan's Law on Statement 4 and Statement 6 is because of the contrapositive rule. The contrapositive rule (also known as Modus Tollens) says that if $A \rightarrow B$ is true, and $B'$ is true, then $A'$ is true.

So to recap:

1. $[A \rightarrow (B\vee C)] \wedge B' \wedge C'$ (Given)
2. $B'$ (Specialization)
3. $C'$ (Specialization)
4. $B' \wedge C'$ (Conjunction)
5. $(B \vee C)'$ (DeMorgan's Law)
6. Therefore $A'$ by Modus Tollens

Your second proof will start the same way. State the given. Use Specialization to get the individual statements out. After that, you'll have to to apply the contrapositive rule twice. I'll post how to do it in spoilers below, but see if you can figure it out on your own.

First application:

> Statement 4 should be an application of the contrapositive on statements 2 and 3. Because you know that $C \rightarrow B'$ and $B$, that must mean that $C'$ is true.

Second application:

> Now that you know that $C'$ is true, combine that with the first statement and apply the contrapositive to reach your conclusion, $A'$

FYI: Here's a good quick reference for most of the basic logic rules.

http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf

Comment: The first three statements on the first proof are not givens. There is only one given and it is $(A\to (B\lor C))\land \neg B\land \neg C$.

Comment: Well, since it's using $\wedge$ to connect them, then they are all trivially true by specialization, but if you prefer you can make Statement 1 the given statement and bump every other statement down one.

Comment: It's not a matter of preference, it's simply how it is. Saying it is a given is misleading, specially to someone who's seeing stuff like this for the first time.

Comment: Fair enough. I will edit the post.

Comment: Interesting... Can this be stated another way without specialization?  The question was asked before the rules of inference were even introduced to me.

Comment: "Specialization" is just one of the technical terms for what is a logical triviality. To put it in plainer English, I can say "You are a stackexchange user AND your username is incanus86". That is a true statement. Therefore, it is also true to say "You are a stackexchange user" and "Your username is incanus86" as individual statements. In logic, saying $A \wedge B$ is true means you can also say $A$ is true and you can say $B$ is true.

Comment: Ah thank you.  For the second then I would say 1 (A-->C)∧(C-->B’)∧B is a given.   2. (A-->C), 3. (C-->B’), and 4. B are specialization.  5. should it just be (B-->c') contrapositive?  6.  is (C'-->A') contrapositive?  7. A' i'm not sure what the justification is here, i think it is modus tollens.

Comment: Yup, you got the last few statements right. When you have an implication statement, like $B \rightarrow C'$ and you already know B, then the conclusion of $C'$ is called Modus Ponens.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is similar to what the OP and Duncan presented. I am using a proof checker to make sure I follow the rules:

[image]

To enter a statement into this proof checker I have to use parentheses if there is any ambiguity, so line 1 is the premise with some added parentheses.

On lines 2 and 3, I used [conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) (∧E) to derive the two conjuncts from line 1.

I used [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (DeM) referencing line 3 to derive line 4.

Finally, I used [Modus Tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) (MT) referencing lines 2 and 4 to derive $\lnot A$ on line 5.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/